# How prove this integral inequality $4(k+1)\int_{0}^{1}(f(x))^kdx\le 1+3k\int_{0}^{1}(f(x))^{k-1}dx$

Tags: integral-inequality

**Question:**

> let $$f(0)=0,f(1)=1, f''(x)>0,x\in (0,1)$$
>   let $k>2$ are real numbers,show that
>   $$4(k+1)\int_{0}^{1}(f(x))^kdx\le 1+3k\int_{0}^{1}(f(x))^{k-1}dx$$

**This problem is from china Analysis problem book excise by (Min Hui XIE)**
,[analysis problem book](http://www.amazon.cn/%E6%95%B0%E5%AD%A6%E5%88%86%E6%9E%90%E4%B9%A0%E9%A2%98%E8%AF%BE%E8%AE%B2%E4%B9%89/dp/B004EBTN6S/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1419779407&sr=1-2&keywords=%E5%88%86%E6%9E%90%E6%95%B0%E5%AD%A6%E8%AE%B2%E4%B9%89)I think we can use 
$$F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt$$
so
$$F(x)=x\int_{0}^{1}f(ux)du=x\int_{0}^{1}f[ux+(1-u)\cdot 0]du\ge x\int_{0}^{1}[uf(x)dx+(1-u)]du=\dfrac{x}{2}(f(x)+1)$$
then I can't,Thank you

Comment: Is $f$ additionally assumed to be non-negative?

Comment: Interesting one ! I got $\displaystyle k^2\int_0^1 f^{k-1}(x)\,dx \le 1 + (k^2-1)\int_0^1 f^k(x)\,dx$, but I don't see how to get the constants $3,4$ right away ! :)

Comment: If $k\gt2$ is assumed to be any real, then $f$ would need to be non-negative. If $k$ is assumed to be an integer, then $f$ could be negative.

Answer (score 4):

**Sign of $\boldsymbol{f}$**

If $k\gt2$ is not assumed to be an integer, then we need to assume that $f$ is non-negative for $f(x)^k$ to make sense. Moreover, if $k=4$ and $f(x)=2x^6-x$, then
$$
4(k+1)\int_0^1f(x)^k\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac45\gt\frac{102}{133}=1+3k\int_0^1f(x)^{k-1}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1}
$$
Therefore, I think it is safe to assume that $f$ needs to be non-negative.

---

**Variational Argument**

To maximize $\int_0^1\left(4(k+1)f(x)^k-3kf(x)^{k-1}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x$ for all $f$ so that $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$ we need
$$
\begin{align}
0
&=\delta\int_0^1\left[4(k+1)f(x)^k-3kf(x)^{k-1}\right]\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_0^1\left[4(k+1)kf(x)^{k-1}-3k(k-1)f(x)^{k-2}\right]\delta f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
for every $\delta f$ that fixes $\int_0^1f'(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$; that is,
$$
\begin{align}
0
&=\delta\int_0^1f'(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_0^1f''(x)\delta f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
To satisfy these conditions for all $\delta f$, we need a constant $\lambda$ so that
$$
\begin{align}
f''(x)
&=\lambda\left[4(k+1)kf(x)^{k-1}-3k(k-1)f(x)^{k-2}\right]\\
&=\lambda 4k(k+1)f(x)^{k-2}\left[f(x)-\frac34\frac{k-1}{k+1}\right]\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
Now we can use the condition that $f''(x)\ge0$. Note that if $\lambda\ne0$, then the right side of $(4)$ changes sign as $f(x)-\frac34\frac{k-1}{k+1}$ does, which it must since $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$. Therefore, we must have that $\lambda=0$. This in turn implies that $f''(x)=0$. Thus, we must have that
$$
f(x)=x\tag{5}
$$
which means
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\left(4(k+1)f(x)^k-3kf(x)^{k-1}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x
&\le\int_0^1\left(4(k+1)x^k-3kx^{k-1}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=1\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$
which is equivalent to the condition sought.

Comment: (+1) very nicely done!! Can't award the bounty before 23 hrs :-) **many thanks!!**

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the statement is false even if $f\ge0$ is assumed.

Let $f(x)=x^{10}$. Then $LHS=4(k+1)\cdot\frac1{10k+1}<1<RHS$.

Comment: That makes it harder.

Comment: Yesterday the statement was $LHS \ge RHS$. Since that it was changed to $\le$... :-(

Comment: And tomorrow, tomorrow (obscure reference to the song "She loves me").

Answer (score 1):

@china math: The [analysis problem book](http://www.amazon.cn/%E6%95%B0%E5%AD%A6%E5%88%86%E6%9E%90%E4%B9%A0%E9%A2%98%E8%AF%BE%E8%AE%B2%E4%B9%89/dp/B004EBTN6S/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1419779407&sr=1-2&keywords=%E5%88%86%E6%9E%90%E6%95%B0%E5%AD%A6%E8%AE%B2%E4%B9%89) doesn't contain this exercise.

Comment: (+1) for the reference, is there an English translation of this book? thank you!

Comment: No. But I have a Chinese electronic version.